# Django ViewSet serializer_class is being ignored

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I have two models: `ModelA` and `ModelB`, with their corresponding serializers `ModelASerializer` and `ModelBSerializer`

In a specific viewset, called `MyViewSet` i have the follwing structure:

```
class MyViewSetRoot(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    # The returned values are of type "ModelA", so I need it to use that serializer
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    queryset = ""
```

Finally, in my actual view, I do something like this:

```
class MyViewSet(MyViewSetRoot):
    get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ModelA_queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
        return Response(
            data=ModelA_queryset,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

I would expect in that case for the queryset to be serialized using the `ModelASerializer` that I specified in the `serializer_class` field. However, I get the error

`Object of type ModelA is not JSON serializable`

If I do this instead:

```
class MyViewSet(MyViewSetRoot):
    get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ModelA_queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
        serialized_queryset = ModelASerializer(ModelA_queryset, many=True)
        return Response(
            data=serialized_queryset.data,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

It works just fine, but **I want to avoid serializing explicitly in the view**.

Any ideas on what could be actually going on? Am I forced to serialize explicitly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to customize the get function. In ModelViewSet, the function for the GET API, is `list` or `retrieve`. But you don't need to redefine it.

```
class MyViewSetRoot(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()

class MyViewSet(MyViewSetRoot):
    pass
```